# Lattice Paths Avoiding Odd Points on Diagonal

Tags: combinatorics

Given that $S_n$ is the number of lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2n)$ that avoid the points $(2i - 1, 2i - 1)$ for $1 \leq i < n$, I need to show that this is equal to the $2n$th Catalan number $C_{2n}$.  I have no idea where to begin on this.  I assume there is some simple categorization of paths so that I can show $S_n = C_{2n-1}C_0 + C_{2n-2}C_1 + ... + C_0C_{2n-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the first point on the diagonal that is reached after $(0,0)$, let this point be $(2k,2k)$.  There are $2C_{2k-1}$ ways to get to $(2k,2k)$ without hitting the diagonal and then $S_{n-k}$ ways to get to $(2n,2n)$ from there without hitting odd points on the diagonal.  We have that $S_n$ follows the same recurrence as $C_{2n}$, we also have that $S_0 = C_{2*0} = C_0 = 1$.  This gives that $S_n = C_{2n}$.